# How to trigger native login behavior with react-native-fbsdk Facebook Login on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

Facebook has come down on our apps because we're (apparently) not implementing the iOS native Facebook Login.  They cite policy 8.2 - https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

We use react native and Facebook's react-native-fbsdk for Facebook Login. Login works great on both iOS and Android.  On Android, it actually appears to use the native component.  But I cannot trigger the native component on iOS.  I expect it to use web when the Facebook app is not installed, but with the Facebook app installed, I cannot get the native component to be used.

I've tried several approaches found on the web.  This SO issue is the same I'm experiencing, but without resolution (iOS fails on 'native_only' and 'native', 'browser','system_account' and 'web' do not trigger the native component) - [How do I set LoginBehaviour when using react-native-fbsdk LoginManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835006/how-do-i-set-loginbehaviour-when-using-react-native-fbsdk-loginmanager/47267836)

This is a great walkthrough, but again, doesn't solve the problem (in my attempts, at least) - https://medium.com/building-with-react-native/coding-with-facebook-login-in-react-native-like-a-pro-1x06-9064fc2f5bfc

Answer (score 0):

it is not supported in iOS newer version anymore..

Comment: Really?  Can you point me to some documentation?  I don't doubt it, but still need to come up with a solution.